# Current Linux support for symbolic links (symlinks) for NTFS 3.1

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, symlink, ntfs, fuse

Symbolic links [have been expanded in Windows](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/),    previously  available only  through administrative privileges. Linux is [documented as supporting NTFS 3.1](https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/ntfs3.html), the version shipped in Windows 10.

**What functionality is available for Linux handling symbolic links on an NTFS mount through basic commands, programming constructs, and  file browsing? How how might the behavior vary depending on whether the mount is through FUSE versus the kernel module?**

[A related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/165389) has been asked, but the information is not as current or detailed as currently requested.

Comment: Windows has supported junction points and hard link long ago so directory symlink isn't quite necessary. Windows generally can't be split into different partitions like Linux so symlink would be less useful as hardlink can fulfill its role

Comment: ntfs3 currently doesn't support junctions but kernel 6.1 will. As for functionality, I've no idea. I wouldn't want to "manage" NTFS links under Linux. Reading is enough.